# Is or are, which one is correct while comparing two things?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which one is correct?

Is okra and lady finger the same? or Are okra and lady finger the same?

Answer (score 1):

The first word in the sentence is referring to more than one thing, so it needs to be "are". That is, the correct sentence is your second one:

> Are okra and lady finger the same?

An alternative, using "is" as the first word, might be:

> Is okra the same thing as lady finger?

This time, the first word in the sentence is referring to only one thing (okra).

Note: this is not particularly relevant to your question, but the common alternative name for okra is not "lady finger", but any one of the following: lady's finger, lady's fingers, or ladies' fingers.
By contrast, lady finger, or ladyfinger is a form of sweet pastry or cake, often used in desserts. See, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyfinger_(biscuit)).